# How to run a task running during sleep mode (modern standby/S0ix/S2Idle)

Tags: power-management, acpi, sleep

The modern standby exists so [Windows can keep network connectivity even when the laptop is in sleep mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/integrating-apps-with-modern-standby#microsoft-store-apps), but [Linux doesn't seem to do anything similar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate). How can I make use of such feature and run some task that makes use of network connectivity?

According to the [kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html#suspend-to-idle):

> The system is woken up from this state by in-band interrupts, so
> theoretically any devices that can cause interrupts to be generated in
> the working state can also be set up as wakeup devices for S2Idle.

What are in-band interrupts?